# Define pointer array length in different file(C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

I am currently making a small console based game. I made a class for enemies, the main character and the game which includes drawing, logic etc and I am using separate files for them.

What I would like to do is to declare a pointer array of class Enemy inside the Game class header and then define how many enemies spawn depending on how many floors you managed to pass.
I hoped that I could do it like this or similar:

game.h

```
CEnemy *en;
```

game.cpp

```
*en = new CEnemy[currentFloor]
```

but this doesnt work of course.. since i didnt declared it as an array in .h file.

```
CEnemy *en[];
```

Doesnt work either.
Can you give me some tips how I could do it?

EDIT: as @WhozCraig suggested i will make an example project with my problem

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Game.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

CGame game();
int main()
{
    game.setup();

    while (game.GameRunning())
    {
        game.render();
        game.input();
        game.logic();
    }
    game.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

game.h

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Enemy.h"
class CGame
{
public:
    CGame();
    ~CGame();

    void setup();
    void render();
    void input();
    void logic();

    bool GameRunning() { return isRunning; };
    void clear();
private:
bool isRunning;
    int currentFloor = 5;
    int stairX, stairY;

    bool enDraw(int, int);
    void nextLevel();

    CPlayer mc;
    CEnemy *en; //part of the problem
};
```

game.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include "Game.h"

using namespace std;
//i left constructor etc out
void CGame::setup() {
    *en = new CEnemy[currentFloor]; //E0349
    mc.setX(width / 2);
    mc.setY(height / 2);
    stairX = rand() % width;
    stairY = rand() % height;

    for (int i = 0; i < currentFloor; i++)
    {
    en[i]->setX(stairX + rand() % 5); //E0044
    en[i]->setY(stairY + rand() % 5);

    if (en[i]->getX() < 0) en[i]->setX(0); if (en[i]->getX() > width - 1) en[i]->setX(width - 1);
    if (en[i]->getY() < 0) en[i]->setY(0); if (en[i]->getY() > height - 1) en[i]->setY(height - 1);
    }
}

.....
```

Error messages:
E0349   no operator matches these operands
E0044   expression must have pointer type
I hope i didnt forget anything

Comment: Are you looking for `en = new CEnemy[currentFloor]` without the `*` in front?

Comment: The sooner you start learning about smart pointers, the better.  What you really want is `unique_ptr<CEnemy[]> en;` (needs `#include <memory>`) and then later `en = make_unique<CEnemy[]>(howManyEnemies);`

Comment: @BenVoigt tried that too but didnt work^^(without the *), nice thanks for the tip! i will have a look into that, didnt know they existed

Comment: Start by including a small, **complete** example of files that exhibit the problem. For all we know you don't even have functions declared, such as `main`. The actual *error messages* , **exactly** as they appear in your compile failure, would equally be considered mandatory as part of your question. Lastly, the statement, "but this doesn't work of course.. since i didn't declared it as an array in .h file." is very likely wrong. I can imagine a plethora of reasons that wouldn't work *none* of which being things we can exclude, because you didn't include a minimum, complete, example.

Comment: You want an array (or other container) of *pointers to CEnemies,*, right? Not an array (or other container) of `CEnemy`?

Comment: @WhozCraig done.. hopefully^^

Answer (score 1):

> What i would like to do is to declare a pointer array of class Enemy inside the Game class header and then define how many enemys spawn depending on how many floors you managed to pass.

If you want to define an array of pointers and you know the total number of floors at compile time, you would need to declare

```
CEnemy * en[NUM_FLOORS];
```

This reads right to left: an array (of size `NUM_FLOORS`) of pointers to `CEnemy`. You could then create a number of enemies on a particular floor `n` with

```
en[n] = new CEnemy[NUM_ENEMIES_FOR_FLOOR_N];
```

If you don't know `NUM_FLOORS` at compile time, you would declare

```
CEnemy ** en;
```

and create your floors at runtime

```
en = new CEnemy*[NUM_FLOORS];
```

---

However, I would highly recommend avoiding managing memory yourself like this whenever possible, as it's easy to leak memory and harder to reason about. You might take a look at using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) instead, which can grow dynamically as needed.

In your example, it might look something like

```
vector<vector<CEnemy>> floors;
```

You could then easily add a floor or modify a floor

```
// Add a new floor with n enemies
floors.push_back(vector<CEnemy>(n));

// Add a new enemy to floor f (assuming the floor already exists)
floors[f].emplace_back();
```

Comment: @2xWollert it will get somewhat more complicated if your `CEnemy` class is an abstract base class, and I strongly suspect that is the case. If so, `std::vector<CEnemy>` will not work. You can still use `std::vector<>`, but the sequence type will desirably be a smart pointer type, such as `std::shared_ptr<CEnemy>`. There are *lots* of examples of dynamic collections with vectors and smart pointers on this site. Search them out.

Answer (score 0):

`*en = new CEnemy[currentFloor]` does not work because the asterisk dereferences the pointer, aka it gives you the object pointed to by `en`. the `new` operator returns the address of the allocated memory, so trying to assign that to a CEnemy does not work.

All you have to do is take out the asterisk like this: `en = new CEnemy[currentFloor]`. Make sure you delete the pointer with the `delete[]` operator.

By the way, if you just need an array with a variable size, use a [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: yea i think i will go with std::vector.. but just removing the asterisk doesnt work.. while it stops giving me an error message for that line, i am still unable to use it. en[i]->setX(...) doesnt work. the error is:expression must have pointer type

Comment: When you have a pointer to an array just use it like a normal array. This is because the name of an array without brackets is actually just a pointer to the first element, and the brackets will automatically dereference it. Try this: `en[i].setX(...)` I'm assuming you just want a dynamic array. If you want an array of pointers thats a different story.